# Regexp, замена двух одинаковых символов одним

Tags: c++, регулярные-выражения

Задание: избавление от буквы c, которая в сочетаниях
сi и сe будет изменяться на s, в сочетании ck — опускаться, а в остальных случаях заменяться на k,изьятие всех удвоенных букв: ee изменят
на i, oo - на u, a в остальных комбинациях будут просто писать одну букву вместо двух одинаковых, а так же отмена артиклей.

Вопрос: не могу разобраться, как заменить 2 одинаковые буквы одной и как передать букву в Replacement.

Заранее благодарю за ответ.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct Lexer {
    vector<string> rule;
    vector<string> replacement;
};

string Parser(string words, Lexer* Rules) {

    //unsigned long length = Rules->rule.size();
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < Rules->rule.size(); i++) {
        regex rule(Rules->rule[i]);
        words = regex_replace(words, rule, Rules->replacement[i]);
    }

    return words;
}

void init(Lexer* Rules) {
    Rules->rule = { "(\\W[A-a]\\W)", "\\W[A-a] \\W", "\\W [A-a]\\W", "^([A-a])", "(\\W[A-a])+$",
                    "(\\W[A-a]n\\W)", "\\W[A-a]n \\W", "\\W [A-a]n\\W", "^([A-a]n)", "(\\W[A-a]n)+$",
                    "(\\W[T-t]he\\W)", "\\W[T-t]he \\W", "\\W [T-t]he\\W", "^([T-t]he)", "(\\W[T-t]he)+$",
                    "(C|c)i", "(C|c)e", "(C|c)k", "(C|c)",
                    "(E|e){2}", "(O|o){2}", "([a-zA-Z]{2,2})*\1" // замена любых одинаковых букв
    };
    Rules->replacement = { "", " ", " ", "", "", // [5] ( [A-a])+$
                           "", " ", " ", "", "",
                           "", " ", " ", "", "",
                           "s", "s", "", "k",
                           "i", "u", "+" //"+" подстановка для двух одинаковых букв.
    };
}

void output(string words) {
    cout << words << endl;
}

int main()
{
    Lexer* Rules = new Lexer();

    string words;
    getline(cin, words);

    ::init(Rules);
    words = ::Parser(words, Rules);
    output(words);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: а вы уверены что это проще делать регуляркой? удаление одинаковых букв как по мне циклом проще обычным.

Comment: `"([a-zA-Z])\\1"` => `"$1"`. А почему у вас `[A-a]`? Вы уверены, что не `[Aa]`? Вот, `(C|c)` надо точно заменить на `[Cc]`.

Comment: Да, это лучше делать через регулярные выражения, потому что это только малая часть задания, а писать 70 if{}else{}  очень не очень.

Comment: Не очень тут всё мне понятно, может, https://ideone.com/xBVECf? (Обновил только что)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew мне нужно было заменить буквы стоящие рядом, чтобы из cacao and Coffee получалось kakao and kofi. Вы как раз таки решили мою проблему
Спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы заменить повторяющиеся буквы одной, нужно

**Найти**:      `([a-zA-Z])\1`
**Заменить**:`$1`

**Подробности**:

- `([a-zA-Z])` - Захватывающая подмаска №1: латинская буква
- `\1` - обратная ссылка, в которой "хранится" значение, захваченное первой подмаской.

В шаблоне замены используется та же обратная ссылка на значение первой подмаски.

Кроме того, `[A-a]` [находит](https://regex101.com/r/201tvB/1) не только `A` и `a`. Замените `[A-a]` на `[Aa]` и `(C|c)` на `[Cc]`.

Используйте

```
void init(Lexer* Rules) {
    Rules->rule = { "(\\W[Aa]\\W)", "\\W[Aa] \\W", "\\W [Aa]\\W", "^([Aa])", "(\\W[Aa])+$",
                    "(\\W[Aa]n\\W)", "\\W[Aa]n \\W", "\\W [Aa]n\\W", "^([Aa]n)", "(\\W[Aa]n)+$",
                    "(\\W[Tt]he\\W)", "\\W[Tt]he \\W", "\\W [Tt]he\\W", "^([Tt]he)", "(\\W[Tt]he)+$",
                    "[Cc]i", "[Cc]e", "[Cc]k", "[Cc]",
                    "[Ee]{2}", "[Oo]{2}", "([a-zA-Z])\\1" // замена любых одинаковых букв
    };
    Rules->replacement = { "", " ", " ", "", "", // [5] ( [A-a])+$
                           "", " ", " ", "", "",
                           "", " ", " ", "", "",
                           "s", "s", "", "k",
                           "i", "u", "$1" //"+" подстановка для двух одинаковых букв.
    };
}
```